# java- using try-catch in the search algorithm error

Tags: java, arrays, search, visual-studio-code, try-catch

i've got a problem when i use try-catch in the search method. when i input the wrong data, it just skips the catch block and output the code below it

```
do {
            System.out.print(menu[1]);
            jumlah = sc1.nextInt();
            System.out.print(menu[0]);
            tujuan = sc1.nextInt();
            for (int i = 0; i < DataRek.length; i++) {
                try {
                    if (tujuan == DataRek[i]) {
                        index = i;
                        nasabah = NamaRek[index];
                        break;
                    }
                } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                    System.out.println("DATA NASABAH TIDAK DITEMUKAN, SILAHKAN COBA LAGI");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        } while (loop2 == 1);
        System.out.println("Nomor rekening tujuan: " + tujuan);
        System.out.println("Nama Nasabah: " + nasabah);
        System.out.println("Jumlah yang ditransfer: " + jumlah);
        System.out.println("Apakah data diatas sudah benar? (Y/N) ");
        loop1 = sc1.next().charAt(0);
```

when i input the wrong data, i expect the output of DATA NASABAH TIDAK DITEMUKAN, but the actual output is the code below it.

Comment: You have to put your `sc1.nextInt();` calls inside the try block

Answer (score 0):

The `InputMismatchException` is potentially thrown by `Scanner`'s methods. You need to include them in the `try` block:

```
do {
    try {
        System.out.print(menu[1]);
        jumlah = sc1.nextInt();
        System.out.print(menu[0]);
        tujuan = sc1.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < DataRek.length; i++) {    
            if (tujuan == DataRek[i]) {
                index = i;
                nasabah = NamaRek[index];
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("DATA NASABAH TIDAK DITEMUKAN, SILAHKAN COBA LAGI");
        System.exit(0);
    }
} while (loop2 == 1);
```